# How to add character after a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to perform a few regex steps, and I'd like to add a quotation mark and a comma (`",`) at the end of these lines without altering any of the rest of the characters in the line.

How would I keep things intact but add the `",`  after the words: `device1`, `device2`, `device3` ?

Example of lines I'm working with:

```
object network device1  
host 192.168.1.11  
object network device2  
host 192.168.1.12  
object network device 3  
host 192.168.1.13
```

After my first step of regex, I have modified my first line to include the curly bracket and some formatting with the words "category" and "name" as shown below. However, I don't want to change the word `device1`, but want to include a quotation and comma after the word `device1`

```
{  
"category": "network",  
"name": "device1  
host 192.168.1.11  
{  
"category": "network",  
"name": "device2  
host 192.168.1.11  
{  
"category": "network",  
"name": "device3  
host 192.168.1.13
```

I can't figure out how to include the `",` with my first step in my regex replace sequence?

I'm using both [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) and Notepad++.

Comment: Please show us the final expected output json and include more sample data which cover as most as possible all cases of your input text.

Comment: There are no closing curly braces, is it a typo?

Comment: Yeah my main goal is to get to a spot where I have the closing curly braces. I'm just stepping through the regex to convert it and I was showing just my first step.  
I have about 5000 "devices" that have differing names.   
Here's an example of what I start with:  
  
object network device1  
host 192.168.1.11  
  
here's what I want to get to:  
  
{  
"category": "network",  
"name": "device2",  
"cidr": "192.168.1.11",  
"type": "cidr"  
}  

so I'm just trying to step my way through the process of changing these lines with a few different regex codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match each entity in your input data:

```
object\s+(\w+)\s+([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+host\s+([\d.]+)
```

This matches:

- `object\s+` : the word "object" followed by a number of spaces
- `(\w+)` : some number of word (alphanumeric plus `_`) characters, captured in group 1
- `\s+` : a number of spaces
- `([^\r\n]+)` : some number of non-end-of-line characters, captured in group 2
- `[\r\n]+` : some number of end-of-line characters
- `host\s+` : the word "host" followed by a number of spaces
- `([\d.]+)` : some number of digit and period characters, captured in group 3

This can then be replaced by:

```
{\n "category": "$1",\n "name": "$2",\n "host": "$3"\n},
```

To give output (for your sample data) of:

```
{
 "category": "network",
 "name": "device1",
 "host": "192.168.1.11"
},
{
 "category": "network",
 "name": "device2",
 "host": "192.168.1.12"
},
{
 "category": "network",
 "name": "device 3",
 "host": "192.168.1.13"
},
```

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vK3xoE/2)

Now you can simply add `[` at the beginning of the file and replace the last `,` with a `]` to make a valid JSON file.

Comment: Nick thank you! I am pretty sure this is exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you everyone who responded on this posting

Comment: @MichaelCaton good to hear. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex `"name": "(device\d+)` but since you have not mentioned any programming language you might get some pattern error based on the language you are using for example `""` in java will need escape character so if you are using java then use this regex
`\"name\": \"(device\d+)`
Now you have to extract group `(device\d+)` and put your `"` there
for example in java you can do it with `string.replaceAll`

Comment: oh gotcha thank you. my first time posting. I believe I'd like to end up with a json file I can upload to an API call eventually.

What if the descriptive name is entirely different instead of it being simply : "device1, device2, device3"  it's could be anything, with various words of differing lengths?
Is there a way to put something like 

"name": "<something here to encompass any amount of characters before a new line>
and then include the ", at the end?

Comment: \"name\": \"(\w+\d+)  try this regex